# Greasemonkey jQuery scope issue

Tags: jquery, scope, greasemonkey

Why do I get a 1, then a 0 when this script runs in greasemonkey:

```
//jQuery source code.....

alert(jQuery('body').size());
(function(jQuery){
    var find = jQuery.find;

    jQuery.find = function(selector, context){
        return find(selector, context);
    };
})(jQuery);
alert(jQuery('body').size());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `this` object when you call `find`. This says 1, then 1:

```
jQuery.find = function(selector, context){
    return find.apply(this, arguments);
};
```